# Apache with virtual hosts to execute python scripts

Tags: python, apache, cgi

For many years I've been using Perl as my CGI but recently decided to start using Python. I thought it would be a simple matter to change my Apache server to use a new language.
Over the years I've done almost nothing with Apache other than regularly add new virtual hosts.

The guts of the conf that I copy and paste to the new file is:

```
        DocumentRoot /var/www/virtual/nik/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/virtual/nik/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/virtual/nik/www/cgi">
                AddHandler cgi-script .pl .py
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

All I did was add .py to the conf.
I have installed and loaded CGID and WSGI mods.
I restarted Apache.
If I put a Perl script in the same cgi directory as the Python, it runs as it should.

Python3 is installed and python scripts run from the command line.
The same script run within a browser gives 500 error.
The shebang is: #!/usr/bin/env python3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

False alarm ... the error was in the Python script.